# Getting a crc32 mismatch while working with DynamoDB local

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

After I make a call to `DynamoDB (using PHP)`  I get the following exception:

> crc32 mismatch. Expected 2745614147, found 2745614147

From the research I've done, it appears to have something to do with gzip but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Also, it probably shouldn't make a difference, but I'm developing with the DynamoDBlocal version at the moment.

**Update**: I was using the new version 3 of the SDK but that seems to have a few problems.  After spending way too many hours trying to figure this one out, I finally just downgraded to the latest version in the 2.* branch and the problem went away.  I'm using the latest version of the local DB that came out just a couple of months ago (2015-04-27).

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information. What version of the SDK are you using? Version of DynamoDB Local? Command line parameters for starting up DDBLocal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182443&tstart=0) in this AWS forum post for a likely solution to your issue.